# Linux Command to merge multiple lines to single line using regular expression

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file, in which I want to find out date(eg. regex) as first occurrence of the line and till the next date is triggered, I need to merge these lines into a single line which will come in between, using linux command & not any programming language.

Note: the next date which will trigger should be also first occurrence of new line.

In short, I need to merge multiple lines into single line using regex pattern with the help of linux command(eg. sed, awk, or any other).

I have tried using sed and awk linux commands but didn't get success.any other linux command is also fine.

eg.

```
date1 Hey.. This is Joe 
Fernandis.
date2 I live in Panjim, 
Goa date3 
what about you? 
date4 have a great day ahead
```

output should be:

```
date1 Hey.. This is Joe Fernandis. 
date2 I live in Panjim, Goa date3 what about you? 
date4 have a great day ahead
```

Comment: sed / awk (and the shell itself) are still programming languages.

Comment: I've updated your question with the changes mentioned in your comment. What is the `date1`, `date2`, etc. format?

Comment: ok...so date1, date2 can be any regex pattern you can consider.like it can be dd–mm–yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: ok...one more thing like we can consider date3 is not there.now can we do that?

Comment: Why is there a linebreak after "Fernandis." in your output?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried. But here's a clue for solving your problem: Use `awk` and write a simple state machine. You could do this in `sed` but I don't recommend it for this type of use.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if the date was a consistent format.

Comment: In your examples don't say `date` - **show** us samples of the dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^date/ ? ors : OFS), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
date1 Hey.. This is Joe  Fernandis.
date2 I live in Panjim,  Goa date3  what about you?
date4 have a great day ahead
```

You'll have to figure out the actual regexp for whatever your date format is by yourself since you didn't tell us what that is or show any in your example.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^date/{:a;N;/\ndate/!s/\n//;ta;P;D}' file
```

If a line begins with a date, append the next line and if that line does not begin with a date, remove the newline between the two lines and repeat. Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.

If the first line of the file will always be a date, use:

```
sed ':a;N;/\ndate/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```